# FORMAT not a Built-in Recognized Function

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014

I have an application that runs fine on my dev PC in the debugger, but I can't get it to work when I run it on other computers. Once I have the deployed the application to another PC that is pointing to a different 2014 SQL Server I get this error:

> FORMAT not a Built-in Recognized Function

CLR 2014 is a pre-requisite of the application, but I verified the proper CLR types are definitely installed on the other server.

One difference is that my SQL 2014 Dev server was installed with the SQL Development 2014 and the production server is a full blown SQL 2014 Server with Windows 2012. I am running the application on Windows 2010 in all locations.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The "different 2014 SQL Server" probably isn't actually 2014. What does `SELECT @@version` return from that server?

Comment: I just found my own answer.  Sorry, I wish I did this prior.  My SQL server is 2008 R2 not 2014 as I thought.  Now it makes sense.  I guess I am re-writing my queries.